# There is a way to remove this black line around my widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I want to make my custom widgets with Canvas, I started with this "radiobutton" thing. The problem is that there are two black lines that I can't make to disappear.

I tried the reliefs, borderwidths/ colors/ highlightthickness/ different widths and heights etc.. both on Canvas and the Frame but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code, I know it is a big mess and there are more simple solutions to make this exact custom button, but my coding skill is low. If there is a solution to make the lines disappear without changing a lot of things on my code, I would thank your help.

```
from tkinter import *


class CustomRadioButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, text=None, textcolor='black', fontstyle=None, width=80, height=30, colorin='#ededed',
                 color='#e6e6e6', colorclick='#dedede', bordercolor='black', borderwidth=0, c_fill='black',
                 c_outlinewidth=1, c_outlinecolor='black', c_size=5, cursor='arrow'):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bordercolor, bd=borderwidth, cursor=cursor)
        self.parent = parent
        self.is_on = False

        self.text = text
        self.textcolor = textcolor
        self.fontstyle = fontstyle
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colorin = colorin
        self.color = color
        self.colorclick = colorclick
        self.bordercolor = bordercolor
        self.borderwidth = borderwidth
        self.c_fill = c_fill
        self.c_outlinewidth = c_outlinewidth
        self.c_outlinecolor = c_outlinecolor
        self.c_size = c_size
        self.textposx = self.width/2
        self.textposy = self.height/2
        self.cposx = (self.width/6)
        self.cposy = (self.height/2)

        self.btn = Canvas(self, width=width, height=height, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
        self.btn.pack(expand=True, side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.r = self.btn.create_rectangle(self.width, self.height, 0, 0, fill=color, outline=None)
        self.i = self.btn.create_text((self.textposx, self.textposy), text=self.text, fill=textcolor, font=self.fontstyle, justify=RIGHT)


class MyFirstGUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='black')
        self.master = master
        master.title("..")

        self.crb = CustomRadioButton(self, text='Test', c_fill='red', width=500, height=240)
        self.crb.pack(side=TOP)

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
my_gui.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: I can't make those lines disappear]

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If all you're asking about is the border, all we need is the widget to see how you're configuring it. We don't need `onClick` or `create_circle` or any of the other functions. Nor do we need the buttons.

Comment: You are stacking widgets, here `self.r` instead of changing the color.

Comment: try `create_rectangle(..., width=0)`

Comment: Set the border color of the rectangle same as fill color: `create_rectangle(..., fill=color, outline=color)` or `outline=''` instead of `outline=None`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `outline` color of the rectangle to be the same as the `fill` color. By setting it to `None` you're in effect telling tkinter you want the default color, which is black.

```
self.r = self.btn.create_rectangle(..., fill=color, outline=color)
```